# protobuf-net v2 alpha - problems with Dictionary<string,string>?

Tags: protobuf-net

I was using a version of v2 of protobuf-net from a few weeks ago quite successfully. (I want to use V2 due to the speed of the pre-compiled serializer running on the Compact Framework.) Everything worked great until I tried to serialize an object with a property of type Dictionary. I received the following error:

{"No serializer defined for type: System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"}

It looked like there were recent changes made to improve Dictionary support, so I grabbed the latest code from today. After building the CF3.5 and FF3.5 dlls, I tried again. Now I get a different error "The model cannot be changed once frozen." If I remove the ProtoMember attribute from the Dictionary property all seems to work well.

Has anyone succcessfully used a Dictionary in v2 of protobuf-net? Is this still too early of a release to be using? My speed tests showed v2 being twice as fast, does that seem accurate (validating my desire to use the less stable v2 pre-alpha bits.)

Comment: This should be fixed (without needing the workaround) from r346 onwards. Please let me know either way.

Comment: Retrieved the latest this morning, works great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is of definite interest. Do you have a specific demo that I can use to investigate? (I'm the author)

---

The problem is simply a bug; during `Compile()` it should cascade the model the see what other types are needed. It doesn't do this at the moment (but [will soon](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=115) ;p). In regular .NET (with `RuntimeTypeModel`) this isn't a problem - it can add in the extra type on the fly. But on CF (or with any static-compiled dll) this is not possible.

Until `Compile()` is fixed, the cheat here is to tell it what else it needs. The easiest way is to touch the indexer for `KeyValuePair<string,string>`:

```
model.Add(typeof(Parent), true);
var discard = model[typeof(KeyValuePair<string, string>)];
model.Compile(...);
```

We don't need the value returned by this indexer (into `discard`) - we just need it to have executed to fill in some blanks before calling compile.

Comment: I think I can put together a basic example and get it to you, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the fix as well as the additional understanding.